# Progress bar with thread

Tags: android-progressbar

Now a days it's my first step in android. I am simply trying to implement progress bar with with a "Download" Button. When i press download button progress bar keep on progressing but when the whole progress gets over i am not able to hide progress bar. Here is my code. please help me.

```
public class ProgressBarDemo extends Activity
{

    ProgressBar pb;
    Button bt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);

        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Thread timer = new Thread()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            for(int i=0; i<=50; i ++)
                            {   
                                pb.incrementProgressBy(i);
                                sleep(1000);
                            }

                                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(ProgressBarDemo.this, "Thank you for downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }catch(Exception e){}

                    }
                };
                timer.start();
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use AsynTask that is a better solution...

```
public class ProgressBarDemo extends Activity
{

    ProgressBar pb;
    Button bt;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        new AsynTasks().execute();
    }
});

}

class AsynTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
        {
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
             publishProgress(i);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
          pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          Toast.makeText(ProgressBarDemo .this, "Thank you for downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
          pb.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: yeah works but with one modification... for( int i=1, i<=100 ; i++)

Comment: take a text view and set 0 in onCreate(Bundle b)as  --txtView.setText("0"+" %"); in starting and then in onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) method set its value like this ---     txtView.setText(values[0]+" %");

Comment: i did it in this way...  publishProgress((int) i * 100/100);   and in the onprogressupdate method    textview.setText(String.valueOf(i) + " " + "%");

Answer (score 1):

You should only modifiy ui elements from the mainThread (the UI Thread) try

```
pb.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    })
```

instead.

Maybe u have to use the same thing for incrementing your progressbar. Alternativley you could use the AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html class. onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute are called in the UIThread automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do UI task from different thread.Use this...

```
public class ProgressBarDemo extends Activity
    {

        ProgressBar pb;
        Button bt;
   @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Thread timer = new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        for(int i=1; i<=100; i ++)
                        {   
                            pb.setProgress(i);
                            sleep(100);
                        }


                                }catch(Exception e){}
                    finally{
                        runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                 pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(ProgressBarDemo .this, "Thank you for downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            };
            timer.start();
        }

    });

}


    }
```

Comment: put your code in finally.Copy above code, I have made some changes

Comment: yeah it's working but taking 1 or 2 min after the completion of whole progress....

Comment: Change this method **pb.incrementProgressBy(i);**  by  **pb.setProgress(i);**